# How to generate lambda functions within for

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, tkinter

#### Info

- python 3
- tkinter

#### Goal

I have a piece of code, that generates a custom menu for me. Now I want to change the color of the single buttons within the menu when the mouse hovers over them.

#### Code

```
for i in cmd:
   button = Button([..set some stuff here..])
   button.bind("<Enter>", lambda name: button.config(bg=hovercolor))
   button.bind("<Leave>", lambda name: button.config(bg=color))
   button.pack()
```

My idea was to bind ENTER and LEAVE events to every button. To get the lambda function to work it needs a name(in this case name, but I don't care about the name).

#### Problem

If the mouse hovers over any button in my generated menu the color of the last button is changed.
I think that is caused by the name of the lambda function. every button generates a new lambda function with the same name, overwriting the previous lambda function in the python environment.

#### I'm searching for:

a way to generate the names for the lambda functions
or
another way to change the color if the mouse hovers over the button.

#### Solved

```
for i in cmd:
   button = Button([..set some stuff here..])
    button.bind("<Enter>", lambda name, button=button: button.config(bg=hovercolor))
    button.bind("<Leave>", lambda name, button=button: button.config(bg=color))
   button.pack()
```

Comment: Is that kivy you're talking about?

Comment: that looks like tkinter to me ... I could be wrong though

Comment: sorry that I didn't mention that. I use python 3 and tkinter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the binding of `button`. Your lambda expression doesn't define it, so it needs a closure to be found in the outer scope (the loop). Since the value changes each time through the loop, by the time the lambda functions are run the `button` variable points at the last button you created, not the one it pointed to when the lambda function was defined.

You can work around this by saving each button object as a default argument:

```
 button.bind("<Enter>", lambda name, button=button: button.config(bg=hovercolor))
```

The `button=button` argument makes `button` a local variable within the lambda, so the changing outer definition doesn't matter. No closures necessary!

Comment: Ok, I changed a bit. now it works: `button.bind("<Enter>", lambda name, button=button: button.config(bg=hovercolor))`

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's happening is as you said, the name gets overwritten and the lambdas all run on the same variables.

What you could do is create a factory of callbacks, so you'd pass the names to the function, and the function would return the callback that'd get called.

```
def create_callback(button, bg_color):
  lambda x: button.config(bg=bg_color)

button.bind("<Enter>", create_callback(button, hovercolor))
```

Comment: pretty sure this would work, I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I'm rather new to python and english is not my mother tongue. what do you mean with factory of callbacks? do you propose to call a function that returns a name instead of writing down a specific one?

Comment: I mean you'd create the function that you'd use, on the fly, by creating it via the Factory pattern, instead of hard coding the function definition like you did with the lambda. You're basically correct, assuming you mean what I just wrote, except that it's not so much returning a name as much as storing the name for later.